# Windows Server Backup MMC is crashing

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-backup, mmc

I'm having a problem with Windows Server Backup. When I want to do anything, I get a window that says:

> blbmmc.dll
>
> MMC has detected an error in a snap-in and will unload it
>
> - Report this error to Microsoft, and then shut down MMC
> - Unload the snap-in and continue running

If I click the first option, the app crashes. If I click the second option, I get this error:

> Unhandled exception in Managed Code Snap-in
>
> FX:{811FD892-5EB4-4E73-A147-F1E079E36C4E}
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Exception Type:
>   System.NullReferenceException
>
> Exception Stack Trace:
>
> at Microsoft.SnapIns.Backup.UI.WindowsBackupNode.HandleException(Exception e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception t)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(Exception e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at             System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.SnapInMessagePumpProxy.Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.ISnapInMessagePumpProxy.Run()
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.ISnapInMessagePumpProxy.Run()
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.SnapInThread.OnThreadStart()

I have no idea what this error means. Does anyone know what is the cause of the error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to enable Inbound Rules "Remote Service Management" (NP In) in Windows firewall, as @kt 2000 wrote in this thread
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/2c8e11f0-020e-459e-b4ed-b2fe30a17342/windows-server-2012-backup-blbmmcdll-mmc-has-detected-an-error-in-a-snapin-and-will-unload-it?forum=winserver8gen. Also, there are few other options, may be helpful to you.

I had the similar issue a while ago, not being able to schedule any backups or make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, we found the solution by ourselves: residual .AVHDX files in the directory where Hyper-V disks are were causing this problem. They generate every time an online backup executes, but for some reason the didn't flush properly and Windows Backup seems unable to handle them.

If you find such files, make sure they aren't part of a VM snapshot or else you could lose information if you delete them / move them. Hyper-V console and file modification time should give you a hint.